# Normalize deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript

So I have this object which represents a hierarchy. What 
Is the best way teaverse it?

For example finding the number of friends at each level, adding a friend at a specific depth.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "Friends": [{
      "name": "Emily",
      "Friends": [{
          "name": "Sandra",
          "Friends": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Michael",
          "Friends": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Sara",
      "Friends": [{
          "name": "James",
          "Friends": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Yara ",
          "Friends": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This question is interesting for me. My solution would be to `JSON.pars()` first then add, delete, show whatever you want.

Comment: This is already in JSON format

Comment: I thought it is text format.

Comment: From my own experience, too general solution may lead to performance risk. It should be enough to limit how deep the code looks for and the certain path to get. Also flat function would be an option as well

Answer (score 2):

This function should suffice, this will give us capability to iterate breadth wise  and we can add/remove objects if we want with some other conditional statements -:

```
function traverseObjectBreadthWise (obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == "array" || typeof obj[key] == "object") {
            traverseObjectBreadthWise(obj[key]);
            console.log(key);
        } else {
            console.log(key, "=", obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I think this will help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use lodash.Its so usefull.You can use count by and you can find count for each level of friends.I use it lik recursive because Friends level can be more.

```
  recusersiveFunc(arr){
    if(Object.keys(arr).includes("Friends")){
        console.log(_.countBy(arr.Friends,"name"));
        arr.Friends.forEach(x => {
          this.recusersiveFunc(x);
        });             
    }
  }

    this.recusersiveFunc(data);//data is your JSON object
```