# Normalize/Flatten a very deeply nested JSON (in which names and properties are the same across levels)

Tags: json, pandas, csv, normalization, flatten

I'm trying to flatten or normalize this very nested json into dataframe with pandas.

Problem is: At every level, the names and the properties are the same.

I haven't found any pandas questions similar to this one. But I do see 2 similar questions but it's in R and JavaScript:
[Normalize deeply nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673804/normalize-deeply-nested-objects)
and [Normalize deeply nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673804/normalize-deeply-nested-objects)
I don't know if you can inspire from these.

My original file is 40M. So here's a sampple of it:

```
data = [
  {
    "id": "haha",
    "type": "table",
    "composition": [
      {
        "id": "AO",
        "type": "basket",
      },
      {
        "id": "KK",
        "type": "basket",
#         "isAutoDiv": false,
        "composition": [
          {
            "id": "600",
            "type": "apple",
            "num": 1.116066714
          },
          {
            "id": "605",
            "type": "apple",
            "num": 1.1166976714
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "hoho",
    "type": "table",
    "composition": [
      {
        "id": "KT",
        "type": "basket"
      },
      {
        "id": "OT",
        "type": "basket"
      },
      {
        "id": "CL",
        "type": "basket",
#         "isAutoDiv": false,
        "composition": [
          {
            "id": "450",
            "type": "apple"
          },
          {
            "id": "630",
            "type": "apple"
          },
          {
            "id": "023",
            "type": "index",
            "composition": [
              {
                "id": "AAOAAOAOO",
                "type": "applejuice"
              },
              {
                "id": "MMNMMNNM",
                "type": "applejuice"
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You see? Names and properties are the same at every level.

I used this line to normalize it. But I don't know how to normalize the objects that are nested in nested objects when they have the same names and properties:

```py
df = json_normalize(data, record_path = ['composition'], meta = ['id', 'type'], record_prefix = 'compo_')
```

```
                                   compo_composition compo_id compo_type id     type
0                                                NaN      AO    basket  haha    table
1   [{'id': '600', 'type': 'apple', 'num': 1.11606...     KK    basket  haha    table
2                                                NaN      KT    basket  hoho    table
3                                                NaN      OT    basket  hoho    table
4   [{'id': '450', 'type': 'apple'}, {'id': '630',...     CL    basket  hoho    table
```

You see in the column "compo_composition" there are still nested objects.

Now I want it to have these columns:

```
compo_compo_compo__id   compo_compo_compo_type   compo_compo__id   compo_compo_type   compo_id  compo_type  id  type
```

Tons of thanks. It frustrates me for days and I haven't found an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your custom parser. This assumes that (a) your JSON is abritrarily deep and (b) every element along the path is unique (ala `table > basket > index`, not `table > table > basket`)

```
# Make a copy so we do not change the original data
tmp = data.copy()
compositions = []

while len(tmp) > 0:
    item = tmp.pop(0)

    if 'composition' in item:
        # If a level has children, add that level's `id` 
        # to the path and process its children
        path = item.get('path', {})
        path[item['type'] + '_id'] = item['id']

        children = [
            {'path': path, **child} for child in item.get('composition', [])
        ]
        tmp += children
    else:
        # If a level has no child, we are done
        compositions += [item]
```

And the final dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([c['path'] for c in compositions]) \
        .join(pd.DataFrame(compositions)) \
        .drop(columns='path')
```

Result:

```
  table_id basket_id index_id         id        type       num
0     haha        KK      NaN         AO      basket       NaN
1     hoho        CL      023         KT      basket       NaN
2     hoho        CL      023         OT      basket       NaN
3     haha        KK      NaN        600       apple  1.116067
4     haha        KK      NaN        605       apple  1.116698
5     hoho        CL      023        450       apple       NaN
6     hoho        CL      023        630       apple       NaN
7     hoho        CL      023  AAOAAOAOO  applejuice       NaN
8     hoho        CL      023   MMNMMNNM  applejuice       NaN
```